# The MathJax newline \\ is broken in tag wikis

Tags: bug, mathjax, tag-wiki

In an attempt to edit the [tag wiki](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/collatz-sequence/info) of [collatz-sequence](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collatz-sequence) I noticed the following strange behaviour.

The conjecture is often stated as a definition by cases and even serves as an example for that notation in [the mother of all MathJax demos](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5025). I tried to apply that to the tag wiki, by modifying its code to that:

```
$$
a_{i+1} =\begin{cases}
\frac{a_i}{2} & \text{if $a_i$ is even}\\[2ex]
3 a_i + 1 & \text{if $a_i$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
```

Which renders just fine here:

$$
a_{i+1} =\begin{cases}
\frac{a_i}{2} & \text{if $a_i$ is even}\\[2ex]
3 a_i + 1 & \text{if $a_i$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$

However, in the tag wiki, not so much:

[image]

As can be seen by the output, there seems to be a problem with the newline which is not interpreted as such. I added the test case

```
$$
a\\b
$$
```

which also renders properly outside tag wikis:

$$
a\\b
$$

The fact that the above behaviour is only present in the tag wiki makes me suspect that it's a bug. Of course, pebkac is always an option and this might be expected behaviour/by design/my fault. Either way, can somebody please explain this?

Comment: that's peculiar ... Could it be related to the fact that in standard LaTeX the `\[` is used to start a new math block? At least it seems to choke on that ...

Comment: @Vogel612 I had tried it without the additional spacing information (that is the `[2ex]` for those that don't know), but that didn't work either. Also, the `a\\b` test case hints at the problem being somewhere else. However, your comment let me start a bit more experimenting and I could reproduce, the problem outside the tag wiki, will post that as an answer for now.

Comment: **flagged**: It's been almost a month now and there is no answer from the people in charge whatsoever. No confirmation if this is a bug or not, if somebody is working on it, if it is of too low priority to be fixed now, etc. I hoped providing the results of my own investigations would help solve the problem quickly. This was apparently not the case.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to reproduce the problem outside the tag wiki.

If one takes the regularly working code:

```
$$
a_{i+1} =\begin{cases}
\frac{a_i}{2} & \text{if $a_i$ is even}\\[2ex]
3 a_i + 1 & \text{if $a_i$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
```

$$
a_{i+1} =\begin{cases}
\frac{a_i}{2} & \text{if $a_i$ is even}\\[2ex]
3 a_i + 1 & \text{if $a_i$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$

and removes one **backslash**:

```
$$
a_{i+1} =\begin{cases}
\frac{a_i}{2} & \text{if $a_i$ is even}\[2ex]
3 a_i + 1 & \text{if $a_i$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
```

$$
a_{i+1} =\begin{cases}
\frac{a_i}{2} & \text{if $a_i$ is even}\[2ex]
3 a_i + 1 & \text{if $a_i$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$

the result looks the same as with two backslashes in the tag wiki.
**I suspect that some process somehow swallows backslashes, before the input is parsed by the mathjax engine.**

> Please be careful brave stackexchange developers, the backslash swallowing monster is loose!

On a more serious note, merely removing a backslash from the second test case

```
$$
a\b
$$
```

$$
a\b
$$

creates a visible error (stuff showing up in red) on the output.

This is **different from the output seen in the screenshot in the question**, where the a b test case renders without error, but also without the newline.

To reproduce that, one has to insert an additional **space**:

```
$$
a\ b
$$
```

$$
a\ b
$$

et voilà, the newline goes missing, without any visible error.

**I suspect that the aforementioned process not only swallows backslashes but produces additional spaces as a result.**

> Beware! It's the attack of the backslash-swallowing-space-pooping mathjax monster. Fly, you fools!

On another more serious note, could somebody with more insights on the code please tame the beast?

Answer (score 0):

You were right about it swallowing backslashes. You need to use a [*real* real backslash](https://xkcd.com/1638/):

```
$$a\\\b$$
```

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: But is this by design?